# Javascript issues missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, mootools, joomla1.5

Few Javascript issues,

I have a joomla site and it has a username check script but when I'm opening it using Firefox I'm getting error but by using Firebug Console to troubleshoot the issue I am getting below errors and I don't know much about this.

The site : http://www.jobodisha.com/component/tpjobs/regjobseekernew.html Check Availability is not working

Its working fine here http://www.digimantra.com/demo/validate.html

Mine Error Msg

1. No relay set (used as window.postMessage targetOrigin), cannot send cross-domain message
2. missing ; before statement

eval("result = "+obj.responseText);

Answer (score 1):

obj.responseText contains an xml but i believe you expect to get a json or js object.
eval complains about exactly this.

However could it be that the site_root variable is not meant to be empty?